# Permission to run telnet from a webpage

Tags: permissions, apache2

I'm trying to run telnet:localhost:2017 from a firefox webpage in ubuntu 10.10.  I have created the necessary file association within firefox to launch telnet, but I think I need to give apache the permissions to run that file.

Any ideas??

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? To open a telnet session in your browser?

Answer (score 1):

The web server does not care what the browser does with regards to handling URIs, since the web server is not involved in the handling, only with responding to HTTP or HTTPS requests. Your problem lies elsewhere.